# Jupyter notebook import error: DLL load failed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[image: **enter image description here**]

I recently install Anaconda and when I tried to open my jupyter notebook I got Kernel error stating failed to load DLL I tried to search for its solution on the web but not found any effective solution to solve it. However, when I previously installed anaconda I did not get this kind of error

I also tried to update my python to the latest version but it doesn't help to get rid of this but this error showing previous version python 37 I don't know what's going on please guys help me

Answer (score 0):

It may be anaconda installer version problem.Did you check your python version with anaconda version?

Comment: my python version is 3.8 and anaconda version is of this 2019.03

Comment: try python 3.7 with your current anaconda version.If it does not work, try to install the anaconda latest version 2019.10 with python 3.7 version